# Eloquent hasOne order by before group by

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have Album model and AlbumItem model - which represents photos.

In Albums model I have:

```
public function first_photo(){
   return $this->hasOne('AlbumItem')->orderBy('sort_order', 'asc');
}
```

In the controller I load Albums list with first photos:

`Album::with(['first_photo'])->get();`

It generates sql query like this:

```
select * from `album_items` 
where `album_items`.`album_id` in (1,2,3,4,5) order by `sort_order` asc
```

But it returns all them album items that has album_id = 1,2,3,4,5...
And I need only first album item which has smallest value of `sort_order` that's why I tried to use GROUP BY but then ORDER BY doesn't work... i.e. I want to change `first_photo()` method so it will first ORDER BY `sort_order`, then GROUP BY `album_id`:

```
select * from (
  select * from `album_items` 
  where `album_items`.`album_id` in (1,2,3,4,5) order by `sort_order` asc
) temp
group by temp.`album_id`
```

Is it possible to get this with `hasOne` method?

Comment: for starter.. `return $this->hasOne('AlbumItem')->orderBy('sort_order', 'asc');` -- please don't, use [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#query-scopes) instead.. *But it returns all them album items that has album_id = 1,2,3,4,5* -- yes, it will, because you're eager loading (and the `AlbumItem` will be mapped to the related `Albums`).. regarding, *And I need only first album item which has smallest value* -- you could use eager loading constraint (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public function first_photo(){
   return $this->hasOne('AlbumItem')->orderBy('sort_order', 'asc')->limit(1);
}
```

This will return just one value. And when we define the relationship and eager load then it will always fire two queries.  You can also add here group by album_id.

```
Album::with(['first_photo'=> function($q){ 
   return $q->limit(1)->groupBy('album_id');
}])->get();
```

Comment: I tried to add `->limit(1)` in `first_photo()` method and it generated query like this `select * from album_items where album_items.album_id in (?, ?, ?) order by sort_order asc limit 1`
Limit won't help... Group by will solve the problem, but results should be sorted before grouping.

Comment: Album::with(['first_photo'=> function($q){
     return $q->limit(1)->groupBy('album_id');
}])->get(); Try this.

Comment: thanks, that did the trick. You can post it as answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i decided to write an answer..

For a starter, you should avoid cluttering relationship with non-relation thingy (`sort`, `order`, `group`, `where`, etc). Change it to be like:

```
public function first_photo(){
   return $this->hasOne('AlbumItem');
}
```

The rationale behind this is that you can do something like [`$model->first_photo()->create([.. relation definition ..])`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method), or you could [`$albumItem->Album()->associate([$model])`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships), or even plainly assign `AlbumItem` instance to `Album`'s `first_photo` relation.

If you wish to **And I need only first album item which has smallest value of sort_order that's why I tried to use**, you can try:

```
Album::with(['first_photo' => function($query){
                                                $query->orderBy('sort_order', 'asc')->first();
                                              }])->get();
```

**Edit**:

Just a bit explanation on how Laravel handles `with()` query. Laravel will first fetch designated `Album`s and then proceed with fetching all `AlbumItem`s that related to the `Album`s. Mappings are done without join, but done in memory by PHP. This is stated (not pretty clear about the in memory part) in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). However, deep in the Laravel's Eloquent Query Builder, they definitely do relation matching in the PHP - it can be found [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L691) and the [`$relation->match(..)` here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.php#L97), well, it's an abstract, one of it's example is [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php#L158). Pretty deep, but you ought to dig part of the framework..

> This loop will execute 1 query to retrieve all of the books on the table, then another query for each book to retrieve the author. So, if we have 25 books, this loop would run 26 queries: 1 for the original book, and 25 additional queries to retrieve the author of each book.
>
> Thankfully, we can use eager loading to reduce this operation to just 2 queries. When querying, you may specify which relationships should be eager loaded using the with method:

Comment: This code generates this: `select * from album_items where album_items.album_id in (?, ?, ?) order by sort_order asc limit 1`
it returns just 1 row, but not 1 row for each album

Comment: @4unkur, just to be clear, with `->with()` query, Laravel will run two queries. one for fetching the `Album`, the second one to fetch the related `AlbumItem` -- all done without join. Mappings will be handled in the code, [reference](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L691)